# Commentary-free launch video?

Tags: launch, nasa

Does NASA broadcast live video of their launches (specifically from Kennedy) that does *not* feature commentary? I appreciate Mike Curie's comments but... sometimes I just want to hear the controllers do their work.

Comment: Some of that information might be ITAR (Internal Traffic in Arms Regulation) sensitive.  This means that they wouldn't be allowed to share it with anyone.

Comment: I feel ya.  The PAO officer on shuttle launches would always be making some "poetic" remark just as the crew called down with something actually interesting.

Comment: @OrganicMarble exactly. I was watching the OSIRIS-REx launch and Curie wound up talking at exactly the wrong time. I usually like the commentary (and it's a lot better than the commentary on the Ariane launches) but, like I said...